# osmsharp : prevent u-turn

Tags: c#, gps, maps, openstreetmap

I need to implement a custom GPS routing engine with OsmSharp. I am using Dykstra routing engine (in the WinForm sample). The sample calculates the shortest road but I want to make u-turns impossible (for instance when reaching the base location).

How would you achieve that ? I have tried some "hacks" in the code but nothing seems to work.

[EDIT]

I found some elements of answers here : https://github.com/OsmSharp/OsmSharp/issues/236

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends.

Firstly, OSM has [turn restrictions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:restriction) which can be used for specifying that u-turns are forbidden (*type=restriction* + *restriction=no_u_turn*). Similarly they are used to allow only certain turns (*restriction=only_right_turn* and so on). Your routing engine will have to support [relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relations) in order to support OSM's turn restrictions.

Secondly, you can solely (or additionally) try to avoid sharp turns by avoiding sharp angles at junctions. This is ideally done by adding a penalty so that the router will still take this route if no other route is available.